# Powershell create new user copy group membership

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to successfully execute a script which has cmdlets from a win8.1 machine to a 2003 domain controller. I set up ADWS on the 2003 domain controller and can now use cmdlets on it remotely from my win8.1 machine.

What I'm trying to do with this script is to get the group membership details from a pre-existing user ($UserOne), create a new user ($UserTwo), create a foreach loop which copies the group membership details from the pre-existing ($UserOne) user to the new user ($UserTwo) that was created.

Currently the script works up until the point of creating the new user ($UserTwo), however the foreach loop afterwards doesn't seem to execute.

Would any of you know what the issue with my code is? I suspect it's how I've entered the foreach loop in directly after creating a user. I also tried creating a new session using Invoke-Command after creating the new user in order to copy the group membership, however none of my cmdlets would work in the scriptblock since the remote server is Windows 2003.

Help would be greatly appreciated, I'm still very much new to Powershell. My code is as follows:

```
$serv = "SERVERNAME"

$cred = "admin\admin"

$secureString = convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext -force

$FirstUser = "NameOne"

$SecondUser = "NameTwo"

$UserOne = Get-ADUser -Identity $FirstUser -Properties memberOf -Server $serv

New-ADUser -SAMAccountName $SecondUser -UserPrincipalName "blah@blah.com" -DisplayName $SecondUser -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $secureString -Credential $cred -Server $serv -PassThru

$UserTwo = Get-ADUser -Identity $SecondUser -Properties memberOf -Server $serv

foreach($group in $UserOne.memberof)
{ 
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $SecondUser -Server $serv
write-output $group
}
```

Comment: I believe you have to give `add-adgroupmember` a user object (not just the name). So when you do `new-aduser` capture that object: 
`$userTwo = new-aduser ...`
then in your loop feed the object back to `add-adgroupmember`:
`add-adgroupmember -identity $group -member $userTwo....`

Comment: @brendan62269 From the help doc on the cmdlet: [The Members parameter specifies the new members to add to a group. You can identify a new member by its distinguished name (DN), GUID, security identifier (SID) or SAM account name.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617210.aspx)

Comment: Just tried that but unfortunately no luck, it's still not executing the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out it happened to be a permissions issue, it's just that I wasn't getting any feedback via error messages!

Thanks for the posts though guys.

Answer (score 0):

I see a number of issues here..

```
$serv = "SERVERNAME"
$cred = "admin\admin"

$secureString = convertto-securestring "Password" -asplaintext -force

$FirstUser = "NameOne"
$SecondUser = "NameTwo"

$UserOne = Get-ADUser -Identity $FirstUser -Properties memberOf -Server $serv


New-ADUser -SAMAccountName $SecondUser -UserPrincipalName "blah@blah.com"`
-DisplayName $SecondUser -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $secureString`
-Credential $cred -Server $serv -PassThru
```

1. Why add the -pasthru if your not going to use it?  This will just needlessly output data to the screen (unless that is what you want).
2. If you assign the resulting value of the command to null, again you will get less screen junk.

Try

```
$null = New-ADUser -SAMAccountName $SecondUser -UserPrincipalName "blah@blah.com" -DisplayName $SecondUser -Enabled $true -AccountPassword $secureString -Credential $cred -Server $serv
```

and

```
$UserTwo = Get-ADUser -Identity $SecondUser -Properties memberOf -Server $serv
```

Why are you doing this?  You already know the user won't be a member of any groups (except default USERS) since you just created the account.  Then you never use the value $usertwo in the script.

```
write-host "Adding user $SecondUser to AD groups."

foreach($group in $UserOne.memberof)
{ 
   Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Member $SecondUser -Server $serv
   write-output $group
}
```